# Specifying join condition "ON columns" in hibernate HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am learning Hibernate, and I have a question about basic HQL join syntax. I am following this [tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-query-language-hql-example). Say I have a Product and Category entity,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class Category {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    private Set<Product> products;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    // other getters and setters
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private float price;

    private Category category;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String name, String description, float price,
            Category category) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    // other getters and setters
}
```

So I have to join category and Product, I will something like this in sql

```
select * from Category A inner join Product B on A.id=B.category_id,
```

In HQL, it seems we drop the "on" condition, the HQL for the above query is

```
String hql = "from Product p inner join p.category";

Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
```

Why is on not required in HQL?

Answer (score 4):

If you have an association (for an example `@ManyToOne`), you don't need `on`, Hibernate will add it to the SQL.

It was a problem prior to Hibernate 5.1, If you don't have an association. From Hibernate 5.1 you can use ad hoc joins:

[How to join unrelated entities with JPA and Hibernate](https://thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/)

Apart that, HQL also defines a `with` clause to qualify the join conditions:

[Hibernate docs: Explicit joins](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join)

Comment: Both links you posted are dead links.

Comment: ftw, with clause can not used with associations with exception message : "with-clause not allowed on fetched associations"